# Varnish 4 and Last-Modified

Tags: varnish, last-modified, varnish-vcl

I have a file "/index.html" that includes "/news.html". I make edits to "/index.html" at 9 AM. I make edits to "/news.html" at 10 AM. If I curl "/index.html" (through Varnish 4) should I expect to see Last-Modified header value reflect 9 AM or 10 AM?

(I'd hope for Last-Modified to reflect 10 AM but I'm not seeing that happen. Varnish 4, caching enabled)

Comment: Varnish Book - Chapter 11 - Content Composition - Page 201 in PDF - 11.3.2 Example: Using ESI.

If your site is sitting behind a CDN that checks Last-Modified header value then esi-date.php will forever show old content.

Comment: @Ronald -- What you say seems to be true. I was just hoping that the Last-Modified value of the last-changed-esi-included-file would "bubble up".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not a definitive answer but here are my thoughts:

I presume you are using esi:include to include the news.html file into the index.html file.

Because I think the esi:include is "lazily" evaluated I would still expect to see the changes made to news.html at 10 AM to be reflected in a call made to index.html after [10 AM + the caching time of news.html].

I guess the Last-Modified Header shows 9 AM because this it the time the index.html file was last changed and this is the response header the backend system provides Varnish with. Varnish simply forwards this to the client.

It does not seem that Varnish is "merging" the values of the Last-Modified Header of the main resource and the esi:includes and using the latest one - which might make sense.